# How to subtract bytes from array?

Tags: c#

How can I subtracts bytes from array to make a new set of bytes. For Example below I need to subtract the first 4 bytes and make new array with remaining bytes of 0x45, 0x54, 0x47.

What do I need to do in order to make new array of bytes from the existing array of bytes by removing the first 4 set of bytes.

```
public static byte[] somebyte = { 0x4f, 0x46, 0x46, 0x53, 0x45, 0x54, 0x47}
```

what I need

```
public static byte[] somenewbyte = {0x45, 0x54, 0x47}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Linq

```
var somenewbyte = somebyte.Skip(4).ToArray();
```

You can also use [Array.Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z50k9bft(v=vs.110).aspx). You have to pre-allocate somenewbyte with the correct size. However, you may find Array.Copy to be more CPU efficient on a *large* array (you won't measure the difference on a small array like this).

Answer (score 0):

With Linq you can do this:

```
var somenewbyte = somebyte.Skip(4).ToArray()
```